# How long does corn take to grow?

Tags: glitch-2011

Is it safe to plant in public lots, or do I need to get a house first? Is it different for different crops?

Comment: knee-high by the fourth of july ;P

Comment: what game? ()()

Comment: Nvm, i didn't realize "glitch" was a game...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corn takes six hours to grow. It does depend on what crop it is.

As far as I can tell, you've got a bit of leeway in the public gardens, but not a heap.

Answer (score 3):

Like Merus said, 6 hours for corn. Each crop you grow takes a different amount of time though. Basically you gotta stand there and use guano from batterflies (found in caverns) if you have crops that you want right away (especially in a community garden). Using guano increases the growth speed crazily - from hours to minutes. However, it's certainly easier to grow crops in your own personal home's plots though.

There are other advantages to having your own home in Glitch, like plots to plant seasoned beans, which allows you to plant tree beans, so you can harvest whatever you need most often that way. My current house has a spice tree, an eggplant tree and a cherry tree because those are the tree harvests I need most often.